# Error --> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server

I have this query

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES
  (SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN ChgDef_id in (678,697) OR (Applicable_At = 'O' AND ChgDef_id in (172,173,191,239)) THEN 'PRE'
      WHEN ChgDef_id in (679,685) OR (Applicable_At = 'O' AND ChgDef_id in (171,253)) THEN 'ONC'
      WHEN Applicable_At = 'O' AND ChgDef_id in (582,733,731) THEN 'WAI'
      WHEN Applicable_At = 'O' AND ChgDef_id in (89,241,734) THEN 'MUL'
      ELSE 'EXTRA'
    END AS Tipo
    ,CASE
      WHEN Cur = 'USD' THEN Result_Std*@Exchange
      WHEN Cur = 'EUR' THEN Result_Std
      ELSE Result_Std 
    END AS Val
  FROM [Feed90].[feed].[Fun_Change_Cargo](0,100)
  WHERE Bkg = @BoL AND Cont_Number = @cont)
```

but the system return the error below.

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

What Can I do?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis (`()`) around your `SELECT` statement and remove `VALUES`. The error is telling you the problem here. (I also suggest declaring the columns to `INSERT` into in your `INSERT` clause, perhaps `INSERT INTO #Temp Tipo`).

Comment: The documentation also provides example on how to perform a `INSERT...SELECT` statement: [Inserting Data from Other Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#OtherTables).